# Remove from latex a foot note

Tags: footnotes, remove

I use the acm template sample-authordraft.tex file.

I see in the pdf at the end of the first column of the first page something with grey color text which start with this:

> "Permission to make digital or hard copies of all or part of this work
> for personal or classroom use is granted without fee provided that
> copies are not made or distributed for profit or commercial advantage
> and that copies bear this notice and the full citation on the first
> page. Copyrights for components of this work owned by others than ACM
> must be honored. Abstracting with credit is permitted. To copy
> otherwise, or republish, to post on servers or to redistribute to
> lists, requires prior specific permission and/or a fee. Request p..."

In which file I can find this and remove it?

Comment: I assume that you're using the `acmart` document class. (If that's not the case, do please provide the missing piece of information.) Please tell us how, i.e., with which options in the `\documentclass` directive, you load the `acmsmall` document class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `nonacm` option.

From the class documentation:

[image]

```
\documentclass[nonacm]{acmart}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\author{A. Uthor}
\title{Title}

\maketitle

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]